# How do I make an authentication service for multiple web services?

Tags: java, web-services, security, scala, authentication

I'm building several different web services, hosted on different machines, but I want a single set of users to be able to access all of these services, yet also have varying read/write permissions between the services. What is the best way to accomplish a secure authentication scheme for these multiple services?

Comment: What Java framework, if any, are you using?  This would help us to answer the question.  By "framework" I am thinking of, e.g., Struts, Spring, Weld, etc.

Comment: I haven't started yet, but I was leaning towards Scala lift.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask]. This question is MUCH too broad for SO.  You could write an entire book on the subject... in fact you should probably start by researching the books available.

Comment: I feel like it's a pretty generic question. With the vast amount of web services out there, particular companies with multiple services, I doubt they're all making their own idea up. I on the other hand, don't even know where to begin. If the simple answer is, each of your services routes incoming requests to an authentication service and requests are then routed back, that's all I really want to understand. If I even knew what books to look for, I would have already done that and wouldn't even be asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very general question, so here's a general answer.

What you are looking for is something with a single authentication scheme for all sites combined with different authorization and access control schemes on the different sites.

The first part is pretty much what a "single sign-on" (SSO) system gives you, though you could do this without SSO.

The second part can be achieved by separating the access rights management from the authorization scheme.  For example:

- Using Spring Security you could create a "UserDetails" service that used a shared LDAP service for user names and passwords, and local database tables for managing "roles".
- Or you could use a single LDAP system for everything, but extend the schema to allow the individual websites access control roles to be represented.

(These are just examples ... not recommendations.  I'm not going to make specific recommendations because it is next to impossible to do objectively, especially since your requirements are so high level.  For instance, a lot depends on the technologies used to implement the websites.)

Answer (score 2):

Currently i'm building a registration system for our projects, similar to what you want. Although we have a different stack: Scala-Akka-Spray, authentication system is based on [Stormpath](http://stormpath.com/) and [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) with some custom internal logic for more REST style session managment. Strompath will give you a good user managment system with quite flexible group settings and Shiro, if you don't use Akka, gives you goog session managemant.